# backend components for SMS on Oxygen

Tags: rooting, root-access, sms, oxygenos, debloat

I took off all google apps and oxygen telemetry using root, but apparently I also took off something important.

I'm now receiving all SMS about half an hour late and I can't send any. This problem persists even if I manually open the app.

I changed the default SMS app to Signal, so I tried to revert to the original 'messages' app by google, but that crashes on launch.

I'm at a loss finding out what essential component I must have removed. Can anyone help out?

Comment: A list of removed apps may help the community to give you better advice.

Comment: Are you sure that it is your phone relying the SMS and not a coincidal problem of your cellular provider? I would first check the SIM card in a different phone. SMS are received by the radio interface layer (RIL) and the handed over to the Android system. The RIL is as far as I know model specific so there is no general answer.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I wish I had one ;) I went a bit over enthusiastic I'm afraid. In the worst case doing a re-flash of the system partition won't be a big deal.

Comment: @Robert I have considered that as well, but I'm not expecting a helpful response from my cell provider :P There is also a good change I just goofed up myself. I haven't had a chance to test with another phone yet.